# Value Passing In Jquery from one html class to other html class in PhoneGap

Tags: html, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am a Iphone developer  now moving to phonegap for making cross plateform application.

I have stared learning jqueryMobile for uiDesgin.It is good.

Issue is here , i am pulling my hairs for is that how do i pass value from one HTML class to other  like we do in IOS or java.Some one has suggested me to use make a global `jquery.js` file keep all variable there and access in you app.

But i didn't understand it.Some one has suggested me to use local storage for value storing and remove after use.I am confused and really not able to figure out how to transfer values from class and also how to keep references of variables and also how to access them.Phone gap advises to use local storage but just for keeping variable reference,

I don't feel it is good.Please advise me how to get started.

Thanks .

Comment: @AmitPrajapati If i have some values in a class and on click i move to second class where i am using values from first class to show on ui.Then in that case also if i need to use local storge.?

Comment: please show some code what you try i can't understand you

Comment: @AmitPrajapati like if i have a array [{name:"alok",age:"21",work:"job"},{name:"ansu",age:"24",work:"job1"},{name:"amit",age:"28",work:"job2"}]  and i have to show only names in first page html and when user click then it shoes the name,age,job information to other page the in that case i only need to pass the  corresponding dictionary in other class to show.If i will use local storage the it will be stored in memory for always.

Comment: you must need to use localstorage and it will easy for you, when you go to next page you can remove localstorage it simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1:

You can pass values with changePage function:

```
$.mobile.changePage('page2.html', { dataUrl : "page2.html?paremeter=123", data : { 'paremeter' : '123' }, reloadPage : true, changeHash : true });
```

or with a button like this:

```
<a href="second.html?paremeter=123" data-role="button">Or through a basic link</a>
```

And read them like this:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#index", function (event, data) {
    var parameters = $(this).data("url").split("?")[1];;
    parameter = parameters.replace("parameter=","");  
    alert(parameter);
});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="widdiv=device-widdiv, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <title>
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>  
    <script>
        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#index",function () {
            $(document).on('click', "#changePage",function () {     
                $.mobile.changePage('second.html', { dataUrl : "second.html?paremeter=123", data : { 'paremeter' : '123' }, reloadPage : false, changeHash : true });
            }); 
        }); 

        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#second",function () {
            var parameters = $(this).data("url").split("?")[1];
            parameter = parameters.replace("paremeter=","");  
            alert(parameter);
        });         
        
    </script>
   </head>
   <body>
    <!-- Home -->
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
                        <a data-role="button" id="changePage">Pass parameters with changePage function</a>
                        <a href="second.html?paremeter=123" data-role="button">Or through a basic link</a>
        </div> <!--content-->
    </div><!--page-->

  </body>
</html>
```

**second.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="widdiv=device-widdiv, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <title>
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>  
   </head>
   <body>
    <!-- Home -->
    <div data-role="page" id="second">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h3>
                Second Page
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">

        </div> <!--content-->
    </div><!--page-->

  </body>
</html>
```

This solution is used for multi-HTML template where one jQuery Mobile page is also one HTML file.

### Solution 2:

Or you can create a persistent javascript object for a storage purpose. As long ajax is used for page loading (and page is not reloaded in any way) that object will stay active.

```
var storeObject = {
    firstname : '',
    lastname : ''
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/9KKbx/

### Solution 3:

You can also access data from the previous page like this:

```
$('#index').live('pagebeforeshow', function (e, data) {
    alert(data.prevPage.attr('id'));
});
```

**prevPage** object holds a complete previous page.

## Solution 4:

As a last solution we have a nifty HTML implementation of localStorage. It only works with HTML5 browsers (including Android and iOS browsers) but all stored data is persistent through page refresh.

```
if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined") {
    localStorage.firstname="Dragan";
    localStorage.lastname="Gaic";            
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/J9NTr/

### More info

If you want to find more information about this topic take a look at this [**article**](http://www.gajotres.net/passing-data-between-jquery-mobile-pages/). You will find everything explained in more details plus working examples.

Answer (score 2):

I am only guessing the things i've understood from your text but I think what you are searching is how to pass parameters in jQuery Mobile between pages on different HTML (my proposed way 2 is the easiest for different html, otherwise same html different pages take solution 1 or 3).

There are three ways:

1) Use HTML5 attributes

a) in HTML page 1, you've got a link, where you need to know on page two the ID "1234", i hope you understood that this ID can be created dynamically:

```
<a data-emp="1234" id="button" href="#home>
```

b) in HTML page 2 or somewhere else:

```
<div id="showParameter"></div>
```

c) in JS whereever you want e.g. pagebeforeload or onClick(): example is onClick:

```
$("#button").on('click', function (data) { 
var anId = $(this).attr("data-emp"); 
$("#showParameter").html(anId) 
});
```

2) Use the URL / Hashtag to pass a parameter

via URL:

a) a link again on page 1:

```
<a href="page2.htm?yourID='1234'"></a>
```

b) JS on page 2 for example on pageInit Event:

```
var parameters = $(this).data("url").split("?")[1]; 
parameter = parameters.replace("yourID=","");
```

3) via Hashtag: http://api.jquerymobile.com/jQuery.mobile.changePage/ by passing a hashtag, google a little bit there are a lot of ressources.

now you are able to work with the parameter on page 2 e.g. calling an ajax with parameter or whatever you want.

hope this helps.