# Should a hash link with a query parameter appended to it work in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

`<a href="#page2?golfer=arnoldpalmer"></a>`

I just tried it and it doesn't work.
jQuery Mobile seems to get rid of the ?golfer=arnoldpalmer part of the link (you can see this via view source).
Any workarounds or solutions?

Is this because the standards are that we cannot put parameters behind page hash links?

Comment: whats your question, are you trying to pass parameters? then check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887132/value-passing-in-jquery-from-one-html-class-to-other-html-class-in-phonegap/18888310#18888310 or are you trying to navigate, then remove your parameter.

Comment: @zyrex yes, trying to pass parameters.

Answer (score 2):

As @zyrex pointed out, there are "pure" jQuery mobile solution.

Another popular solution is to rely on [Backbone Routers](http://backbonejs.org/#Router) which provide out of the box parsing of parameters in URLs.

Should you use this, you must deactivate hashtag interception in JQuery Mobile using

```
$( document ).on( "mobileinit",
    // Set up the "mobileinit" handler before requiring jQuery Mobile's module
    function() {
        // Prevents all anchor click handling including the addition of active button state and alternate link bluring.
        $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;

        // Disabling this will prevent jQuery Mobile from handling hash changes
        $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
    }
)
```

Create Routes in the Router

```
 routes: {

     "": "start",

     "page2/:golfer": "gotopage2"
 }
```

And do JQM navigation in your handler

```
gotopage2: function( golfer ) {

    //do something with golfer

    //show JQM page
    $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer( "change", "#page2")                    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this should solve your problem :) there are three ways to pass parameters.
[Value Passing In Jquery from one html class to other html class in PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887132/value-passing-in-jquery-from-one-html-class-to-other-html-class-in-phonegap/18888310#18888310)